# Google Sheets ISBETWEEN nested function pulling values outside of set range

Tags: google-sheets, google

I am using a nested ISBETWEEN function with the filter function to pull a list of items that fall in a certain range. Im using this forumula:

=FILTER(U7:U,ISBETWEEN(V7:V,U5,V5))

U7:U is a list of product SKUS
V7:V is a performance metrice
and U5 & V5 are the low and high values I want to filter through

I have one specific issue in that just ONE value is sorting incorrectly. I have two sheets one that sorts for the value between 0-0.99 and the other for values 1-1.5. For some reason it's adding in a SKU that has a value 0.5 to both. I've tried adding additional FALSE/TRUE arguments just as an experiment and that didn't solved it.

[image: Formuala]

Answer (score 0):

XD I had a cell hidden from myself in that column with values in it for some reason I deleted it and that remedied the issue